# como mostrar una pagina de mantenimiento solo a los usuarios y no a los adms

Tags: php, pdo

hola estoy creando un sistema de mantenimiento y quiero que solo se muestre a los usuarios que no tienen el rol de admin y que no esten logueados
el problema es que no tengo idea en que me estoy equivocando en mi codigo ya que me salta una pagina en blanco o me salta la pagina de mantenimiento pero si estoy logeado como administrador me sigue mostrando la pagina de mantenimiento

> Edit con lo de rimuru

si estoy con mi cuenta me aparece en blanco y si no estoy logeado con mi cuenta me aparece la pagina de mantenimiento

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'bin/core/conexion.php';
function mantenimiento ($base, $bool) {
  // $bool es un boleano
  // la variable $bool determina si el usuario esta o no conectado
  $sql="SELECT * FROM mantenimiento WHERE id = 1";
  $resultado = $base->prepare($sql);
  $resultado->execute(array());
  while ($row = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $mant = $row['man'];
    if ($bool) {
      // aquí verificamos que el usuario este conectado y obtenemos su role
      $user = $_SESSION["user"];
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email = '" . $user . "'";
      $perfil_info = $base->prepare($sql);
      $perfil_info->execute(array());
      if ($crow = $perfil_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        if ($mant === "yes") {
          if ($crow["role"] === "admin") {
            include "home.php";
          } else {
            include "man.php";
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      // sino esta conectado
      if ($mant == "yes") {
        include "man.php";
      } else {
        include "home.php";
      }
    }
  }
}
try {
  if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    // el usuario no esta conectado
    mantenimiento($base, false);
  } else {
   // el usuario esta conectado
   mantenimiento($base, true);
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Fallo en la base datos" . $e->getMessage();
}
?>

y este es mi archivo de conexion

<?php
//Configuracion General
$web = " "; //Url de la web Ej  [sin / al final]
$home = "index"; //EN CASO DE FALLO EN EL HOSTIG POR QUE NO RECONOSE los archivos se añade el valor "index" 
$titulo = " "; //Se muestra en la pagina principal 
$desc = "";





//conexion a Mysql mediante PDO
$base = new PDO('mysql:host= ; dbname= ;charset=utf8',' ',' ');
$base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$base->exec("set names utf8mb4");
?>
```

Comment: No es necesario que repitas una consulta, con una basta.

Answer (score 0):

**Editada**

No es necesario que repitas la misma consulta, y para hacer lo que quieres es muy simple.

```php
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'bin/core/conexion.php';
function mantenimiento ($base, $bool) {
  // $bool es un boleano
  // la variable $bool determina si el usuario esta o no conectado
  $sql="SELECT * FROM mantenimiento WHERE id = 1";
  $resultado = $base->prepare($sql);
  $resultado->execute(array());
  while ($row = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $mant = $row['man'];
    if ($bool) {
      // aquí verificamos que el usuario este conectado y obtenemos su role
      $user = $_SESSION["user"];
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email = '" . $user . "'";
      $perfil_info = $base->prepare($sql);
      $perfil_info->execute(array());
      while ($crow = $perfil_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        if ($mant === "yes") {
          // verificamos que este en mantenimiento
          if ($crow["role"] === "admin") {
            include "home.php";
          } else {
            include "mant.php";
          }
        } else {
          // fuera de mantenimiento
          include "home.php";
        }
      }
    } else {
      // sino esta conectado
      if ($mant === "yes") {
        include "mant.php";
      } else {
        include "home.php";
      }
    }
  }
}
try {
  if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    // el usuario no esta conectado
    mantenimiento($base, false);
  } else {
   // el usuario esta conectado
   mantenimiento($base, true);
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Fallo en la base datos" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: acabo de editar mi post

Comment: @Max quizás te funcioné así.

Comment: ahora la pagina quedo en blanco xd

Comment: pero solo si estoy en mi cuenta

Comment: @Max algún error o tu archivos `home.php` o `mant.php` estén mal

Comment: hum la verdad me encantaria pasarte una cap de ambos pero son para una web h el home.php carga perfectamente el problema es en la parte de index.php donde se hace la consulta de si esta en mantenimiento o no

Comment: @Max tal vez ese `if ($crow = ...` debería ser un `while ($crow = ...` así como edite mi respuesta

Comment: pues nop sigue en blanco note que si paso de yes a no la pagina queda en blanco y tengo que ir al /logout para que me cargue bien el home

Comment: @Max [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102142/discussion-between-rimuru-tempest-and-max).